Flutter web app issue - debugger: Error calculating Dart variables for frame 107:
I'm suddenly getting issues with my Flutter web app - the following error messages are appearing in the Intellij debug panel...
Debugger: Error calculating Dart variables for frame 107: WipError -32000 Could not find object with given id
Debugger: Error calculating Dart variables for frame 108: WipError -32000 Could not find object with given id
Debugger: Error calculating Dart variables for frame 109: WipError -32000 Could not find object with given id
Debugger: Error calculating Dart variables for frame 110: WipError -32000 Could not find object with given id

The Flutter doctor call shows..
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.24.0 on channel stable at d:\Ian\Documents\sdk\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 80c2e84975 (2 weeks ago), 2024-07-30 23:06:49 +0700
    • Engine revision b8800d88be
    • Dart version 3.5.0
    • DevTools version 2.37.2

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.8)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.32002.261
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1
    • Flutter plugin version 81.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 241.18968.26

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.120
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 127.0.2651.86

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

Any suggestions?

I upgraded to the latest IntelliJ and the problem no longer occurs
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\Ian\Documents\github\good_day> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.24.0 on channel stable at d:\Ian\Documents\sdk\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 80c2e84975 (3 weeks ago), 2024-07-30 23:06:49 +0700
    • Engine revision b8800d88be
    • Dart version 3.5.0
    • DevTools version 2.37.2

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.8)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.32002.261
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1
    • Flutter plugin version 81.1.3
    • Dart plugin version 242.20629

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.120
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 127.0.2651.86

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

